# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting operation

Tags: python, python-3.4

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQUTY.png) [Desired outputvariant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT02Z.png) Can't seem to find what's wrong with this bit of python code:

```
print('%-*s', low, '%-*s', mid, ' %-*s', high, '%-*s'
      % (8, "", (var_range//3), "", (var_range//3), "", (var_range//3), ""))
```

I am trying to space the variables: `low`, `mid`, and `high` based on input from the user (`var_range//3`). The (var_range//3) acts as customized spacing. I want the output to vary depending on the range by the user

P.S. I am using Python 3.4.4

Comment: The `%` _operator_ expects the formatting string to contain as many `%` _formatting specifiers_ as there are in the tuple following it. In your code snippet the formatting string being used is only the last `'%-*s'` yet the tuple following it contains 8 things (the `(8, "", (var_range//3), "", (var_range//3), "", (var_range//3), "")`).

Comment: When I only use 4 things: (8,(var_range//3),(var_range//3),(var_range//3))), the same error exists

Comment: The format string `'%-*s'` only expect one item to be in given because _that string_ only contains one `'%'` character (not 8 or even 4). You might find it easier to use the [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method which doesn't using `'%'` characters at all. I think you're confusing the fact that they're used for two different things here—as both a string _operator_ **and** what that operator expects in the formatting _string_ it get passed as part of the entire expression.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of what the desired output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

I not exactly sure what output you're attempting to produce, but this example might help:

```
var_range = 99
print('%*s %*s %*s' % (8, var_range//3, 8, var_range//3, 8, var_range//3))
```

Output:

```
  33       33       33
```

This format string requires 3 pairs of values for a total of 6 in the tuple that follows it. The first value of each pair is the field width (`8` in all three cases), and the second value is the numeric value to display (which is also the same in very case because you've repeated `var_range//3` three times as well).

I also changed the formatting for each value from `'%-*s` to `'%*s` so the value display is right-justify instead of left-justified with the width. See the [string formatting documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) for details.

Comment: I added pictures of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use [newer style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> var_range=24
>>> print('{:<{fill}}{:<{fill}}{:<{fill}}'.format(2, 12, 22, fill=var_range//3))
       2      12      22
```

Since your pattern is the same for each, create the formatting for one field and repeat it 3 times.

```
>>> print(('{:>{fill}}' * 3).format(2, 12, 22, fill=var_range//3))
       2      12      22
```